# Java threading NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm relatively new to Java and I am trying to make a login page for my desktop application. I have a thread called "listen" that should be called when the application first opens, its job is to check weather the username and password fields are not blank.

```
public class Login extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtUsername;
    private JPasswordField pwdPassword;
    private JLabel lblUsername;
    private JButton btnLogin;
    private JLabel lblPassword;
    private JCheckBox cboxRemember;
    private Thread run, listen;
    private boolean running = true;

public Login() {
    createWindow();
    run = new Thread(this, "Running");
    running = true;
    run.start();    
}

private void createWindow() {
     //application layout and actionListener for login button
}

public void run() {
    listen();

}

public void listen() {
    listen = new Thread("Listen") {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                if (txtUsername.getText().equals("") || pwdPassword.getText().equals("")) btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
                else btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };
    listen.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Login frame = new Login();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Whenever i try to execute my code the 'listen' thread throws a NullPointerException on this line `if (txtUsername.getText().equals("") || pwdPassword.getText().equals("")) btnLogin.setEnabled(false);` I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your `txtUsername` and `pwdPassword` JTextField's are empty when the application starts.

Comment: you will gt a NPE if txtUsername.getText() returns null ..... add a check for that and it should be the first check. Something like (txtUsername.getText()!=null && (txtUsername.getText().equals("") || pwdPassword.getText().equals(""))).

Ohh and @Trobbins mentioned , the same goes for pwdPassword field too :)

Comment: When do you assign a value to `txtUsername`? It's clearly not got one (except `null`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're if{} block gets executed before any initialization. Add

```
if (txtUsername.getText()!=null &&( txtUsername.getText().equals("") || pwdPassword.getText().equals("")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your txtUserName and pwdPassword:

```
 txtUsername = new JTextField();
 pwdPassword = new JPasswordField();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since txtUsername and pwdPassword have not been initialized, you will get a NPE in your IF{} statement.